# Does Smart Contract pay gas fees in this case?

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript, ethers.js, react

Lets say there are 2 smart contracts A and B. **A contracts approves B contract for some allowance**, as B has approval to withdraw from A contract. Lets say contract B withdraw some X coins from A contract, **Does A contract pay fees for this transaction (Sending X coins from A to B)**?

Answer (score 1):

Whoever initiates the transaction pays for the transaction fees. This is usually the end user interacting with the smart contract, but could be the smart contract in some cases of on-chain automation like Acala EVM+ [Schedule predeploy](https://evmdocs.acala.network/network/precompiled-and-predeployed-smart-contracts/schedule).

Comment: Do you know of any EIP to allow normal EVM contracts to pay for their own gas?